# Order of 'const' variables in React Stateless Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, constants, react-16

Say I have a simple React stateless component like so:

```
const myComponent = () => {
    const doStuff = () => {
        let number = 4;

        return doubleNumber(number);
    };

    const doubleNumber = number => {
        return number * 2;
    };

    return <div>Hello {doStuff()}</div>;
};

export default myComponent;
```

Based on the eslint error I receive, and my understanding of how 'const' works, I assumed that this component would not render, since the function 'doubleNumber()' is used by the function 'doStuff()' before it is initialized. However, whenever I use this component, it renders as expected - why doesn't it throw an exception? Does this mean the order of 'const' variables in React components can be whatever we like?

Comment: The method `doStuff` is intialized before `doubleNumber` is intialized but it is called ( executed ) after `doubleNumber` is intialized.

Comment: They are all in scope at the time the function is called, so I don't see the problem. It also doesn't have anything to do with React or stateless components

Comment: Linting errors don't always equate to runtime errors.  Linting is used to enforce code style guidelines as well as things that could be actual errors.

Comment: "*Based on the eslint error I receive*" - **what** error do you receive? Please post the message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the code works is because the body of `doStuff` isn't executed until it's invoked. Since `doubleNumber` happened to be defined before `doStuff` was called, everything is fine, but the code is correctly identified as brittle by the linter because the dependency inversion.

The crash occurs only if you happened not to initialize `doubleNumber` by the time `doStuff` was called:

```
const doStuff = () => doubleNumber(4);
doStuff(); // ReferenceError: doubleNumber is not defined
const doubleNumber = number => number * 2;
```

which seems obvious here, but in more complex cases may not be so clear.

`const` versus `let` should have no bearing on the linter's output because although they're hoisted, they cannot be accessed until initialized.

The order *can be* whatever you like, assuming calls are only made once dependencies are available, but that doesn't make it a good idea (which is exactly what linting is supposed to identify).

Comment: "*neither is hoisted*" - actually, both are hoisted, otherwise it wouldn't be possible to refer to them from the function (body) above the declaration.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. That makes sense--corrected (hopefully).

Comment: Does look good :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your case is described in the [Typescript documentation of Block scoped variables](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html#block-scoping) (navigate to the last bit of that section).

It says :

> you can still capture a block-scoped variable before it’s declared.
>   The only catch is that it’s illegal to call that function before the
>   declaration. If targeting ES2015, a modern runtime will throw an
>   error; however, right now TypeScript is permissive and won’t report
>   this as an error.

And the example given is

```
function foo() {
    // okay to capture 'a'
    return a;
}

// illegal call 'foo' before 'a' is declared
// runtimes should throw an error here
foo();

let a;
```

In your case, `doubleNumber` is being captured inside `doStuff`, but `doubleNumber` is declared before `doStuff` and hence is okay according to the docs, just like the variable `a` in the documentation's example.